# how to restart a parameter function inside function -javascript

Tags: javascript

I am doing something like "if there is b_array item in a_array then get b_array refresh else a_array concat b_array ". But b_array is an array not a function, how to activate it again in the function?

```
function a_concat_b(a_array,b_array){

  function findItem(){
    for (var i = 0; i < b_array.length; i++) {
      if (a_array.indexOf(b_array[i])!=-1) {
        return true;   //if there is b_array item in a_array return true
      };
    }
    return false;
  }

  if (findItem()) {   //if there is b_array item in a_array return true
    a_concat_b(a_array,b_array);  //redo random_array(5); to get a new array
  }else {
    a_array = a_array.concat(b_array);
    return a_array;
  };
}

function random_array(x){
  var a =[];
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {     
    a.push(Math.floor(Math.random()*x));
    console.log(a);
  };
  return a;
}

console.log(a_concat_b([1,2,3],random_array(5)));
```

Comment: In the case where the findItem() returns true (which looks like it will be often), your function calls itself recursively with the original parameters.  This will recurse until the stack overflows.

Comment: What's the goal?  Do you want to concat the two arrays, but only after removing duplicates from the second array?